# Kotlin testing with koin

Tags: kotlin, ktor, koin

I keep on getting the trouble that says A koin applications is already running. This is my code where i wanna test my server code... And it is not working what have i done wrong? i have checked this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufoTXJ0eRQY&list=PLQkwcJG4YTCQDFGWBnwIFnOdfp4CDRB-Z&index=10 i have looked at the documentation but nothing works.

```
package com.PapperSeller.routes

import com.PapperSeller.data.models.User
import com.PapperSeller.di.testModule
import com.PapperSeller.repository.user.FakeUserRepository
import com.PapperSeller.util.ApiResponseMessages
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.koin.core.context.stopKoin
import org.koin.dsl.module
import org.koin.test.KoinTest
import org.koin.test.inject
import kotlin.test.AfterTest
import kotlin.test.BeforeTest
import kotlin.test.Test


internal class UserRoutesKtTest : KoinTest{
    private val testUserRepository by inject<FakeUserRepository>()

    @BeforeTest
    fun setUp(){


        startKoin {
            modules(testModule)

        }
    }
    @AfterTest
    fun junk(){
        stopKoin()
    }


    @Test
    fun `Create user, no body attached, responds with BadRequest`() = testApplication{
         
    }

    @Test
    fun `Create user, user already exists, responds with unsuccessfull`() = testApplication{
        routing {
            createUserRoute(testUserRepository)
        }
        val testUser = User(email = "testAccount@hotmail.com", username = "testUser", password = "testPassword")
        val client = createClient {
            install(ContentNegotiation){
                json()
            }
        }
        val response = client.post{
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)

        }

        assertThat(response.bodyAsText()).isEqualTo(ApiResponseMessages.USER_ALREADY_EXIST)



    }


}
```

this is my error logg

```
2023-03-18 13:49:53.705 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @call-context#2] INFO  ktor.test - No ktor.deployment.watch patterns specified, automatic reload is not active.

A Koin Application has already been started
org.koin.core.error.KoinAppAlreadyStartedException: A Koin Application has already been started
    at app//org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.register(GlobalContext.kt:44)
    at app//org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.startKoin(GlobalContext.kt:57)
    at app//org.koin.core.context.DefaultContextExtKt.startKoin(DefaultContextExt.kt:34)
    at app//org.koin.ktor.plugin.KoinPluginKt$Koin$2.invoke(KoinPlugin.kt:37)
    at app//org.koin.ktor.plugin.KoinPluginKt$Koin$2.invoke(KoinPlugin.kt:35)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.CreatePluginUtilsKt.setupPlugin(CreatePluginUtils.kt:301)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.CreatePluginUtilsKt.createPluginInstance(CreatePluginUtils.kt:270)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.CreatePluginUtilsKt.access$createPluginInstance(CreatePluginUtils.kt:1)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.CreatePluginUtilsKt$createApplicationPlugin$2.install(CreatePluginUtils.kt:90)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.CreatePluginUtilsKt$createApplicationPlugin$2.install(CreatePluginUtils.kt:83)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.ApplicationPluginKt.install(ApplicationPlugin.kt:98)
    at app//com.PapperSeller.ApplicationKt.module(Application.kt:13)
    at java.base@17.0.4.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.4.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.4.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.4.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
    at app//kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Static.call(CallerImpl.kt:106)
    at app//kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:108)
    at app//kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflection(KCallableImpl.kt:159)
    at app//kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:112)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.callFunctionWithInjection(CallableUtils.kt:119)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.executeModuleFunction(CallableUtils.kt:36)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:330)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:355)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:330)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:32)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:311)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:309)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:337)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:309)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:150)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:276)
    at app//io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine.start(TestApplicationEngine.kt:142)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngine$DefaultImpls.start$default(ApplicationEngine.kt:68)
    at app//io.ktor.server.testing.client.TestHttpClientEngine.execute(TestHttpClientEngine.kt:47)
    at app//io.ktor.server.testing.client.DelegatingTestClientEngine.execute(DelegatingTestClientEngine.kt:56)
    at app//io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine$executeWithinCallContext$2.invokeSuspend(HttpClientEngine.kt:99)
    (Coroutine boundary)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine$DefaultImpls.executeWithinCallContext(HttpClientEngine.kt:100)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpClientEngine.kt:70)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpSend$DefaultSender.execute(HttpSend.kt:138)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRedirect$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpRedirect.kt:61)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$3.invokeSuspend(HttpCallValidator.kt:147)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpSend$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpSend.kt:104)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpCallValidator.kt:126)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpRequestLifecycle.kt:35)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClient.execute$ktor_client_core(HttpClient.kt:191)
    at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement.executeUnsafe(HttpStatement.kt:108)
    at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement.execute(HttpStatement.kt:47)
    at com.PapperSeller.routes.UserRoutesKtTest$Create user, no body attached, responds with BadRequest$1.invokeSuspend(UserRoutesKtTest.kt:80)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationKt$testApplication$builder$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestApplication.kt:288)
Caused by: org.koin.core.error.KoinAppAlreadyStartedException: A Koin Application has already been started
    at app//org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.register(GlobalContext.kt:44)
    at app//org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.startKoin(GlobalContext.kt:57)
    at app//org.koin.core.context.DefaultContextExtKt.startKoin(DefaultContextExt.kt:34)
    at app//org.koin.ktor.plugin.KoinPluginKt$Koin$2.invoke(KoinPlugin.kt:37)
    at app//org.koin.ktor.plugin.KoinPluginKt$Koin$2.invoke(KoinPlugin.kt:35)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.CreatePluginUtilsKt.setupPlugin(CreatePluginUtils.kt:301)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.CreatePluginUtilsKt.createPluginInstance(CreatePluginUtils.kt:270)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.CreatePluginUtilsKt.access$createPluginInstance(CreatePluginUtils.kt:1)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.CreatePluginUtilsKt$createApplicationPlugin$2.install(CreatePluginUtils.kt:90)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.CreatePluginUtilsKt$createApplicationPlugin$2.install(CreatePluginUtils.kt:83)
    at app//io.ktor.server.application.ApplicationPluginKt.install(ApplicationPlugin.kt:98)
    at app//com.PapperSeller.ApplicationKt.module(Application.kt:13)
    at java.base@17.0.4.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.4.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.4.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.4.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
    at app//kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Static.call(CallerImpl.kt:106)
    at app//kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:108)
    at app//kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflection(KCallableImpl.kt:159)
    at app//kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:112)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.callFunctionWithInjection(CallableUtils.kt:119)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.executeModuleFunction(CallableUtils.kt:36)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:330)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:355)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:330)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:32)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:311)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:309)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:337)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:309)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:150)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:276)
    at app//io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine.start(TestApplicationEngine.kt:142)
    at app//io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngine$DefaultImpls.start$default(ApplicationEngine.kt:68)
    at app//io.ktor.server.testing.client.TestHttpClientEngine.execute(TestHttpClientEngine.kt:47)
    at app//io.ktor.server.testing.client.DelegatingTestClientEngine.execute(DelegatingTestClientEngine.kt:56)
    at app//io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine$executeWithinCallContext$2.invokeSuspend(HttpClientEngine.kt:99)
    at app//kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

Comment: Can you please try to apply this recommendation https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-5608#focus=Comments-27-6912159.0-0?